# Getting the navMesh as an object which the navMeshAgent's destination is to

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a setup where mesh A is the navMesh the agent is currently on, and B is what the agent has the destination of. I could get the A with navMesh.navMeshOwner; simple. However, how do I get B as an object?

This question was aroused from my need to make a conditional statement to tell agent's destination is not on the same navMesh because if I do not set the stoppingDistance of the agent to 0 the agent will never reach the traversing point of A from B by the stoppingDistance.

Comment: You could use `GameObject.Find("B")` and then do whatever you need with that GameObject (get the navmesh component of it etc)

Comment: @TheSkimek Find object by name? I dunno... I'm thinking getting gameObject by distance would be better if non-else...

Comment: You can find the object by tag also. Distance? Lets say another object is right on the center of object B -> both objects have the same distance to mesh A......what are you doing then? Distance is the a really bad way to find another object (at least for what you seem to need). Whats the problem with finding it by name/tag? Just do it once at the start of the game and its done.

Comment: @TheSkimek Because of iteration. The case scenario with just two navMesh are for simpler testing purpose and I'm worried about it if I make it find whole set of terrains(navMesh) by name.

Comment: So you rather go trough ALL objects in your scene to find every object that is (lets say) 5 Units away from mesh A? How does that make sense? It would still be possible to find >1 objects, when there is something on the same spot. Also you would have to change your script everytime you move either mesh A or mesh B, because they then have a different distance than you specified. (doing that for every set of your terrains)

Comment: @TheSkimek I didn't say I'd find all objects every time. Using GameObject.Find was your suggestion I didn't say I'd do so yet. If I'd have done it by distance check I'd just do a sphereCast and evaluate the closest mesh that is a navMesh, but that's still just assumption of if I'd have done it by finding gameObject. This question I thought was simpler than that... If NavMesh or NavMeshAgent or its correlated functions would have a data store that is similar to navMeshAgent.navMeshOwner this would have been much easier. My question was more of in that notion.

Comment: cont'd // Because navMeshAgent.destination returns a vector from destination transform and the position of it on that same navMesh I thought in reverse there was something I missed on using things in NavMesh...

Comment: But this way you would still end up iterating over all objects that are hit by the sphereCast to find the closest navMesh then. And my comment before would still apply: You would have to change your script (the radius of the sphereCast) everytime you move the objects. What exactly are you trying to accomplish by getting B as an object. Is it possible to merge Navmesh A and Navmesh B to one Navmesh and then use off-Mesh links for whatever you want to do? (getting from island A to island B for example)

Comment: Ah, something I can clarify much clearer.  In my setup I am not using offMeshLink. I'm turning on and off of navMeshAgent.enable and then use rigidbody to traverse severed navMeshes to achieve the movement pattern I desired. Since I found out I could get the current navMesh with nabeMeshAgent.navMeshOwner what O asked followed in need.

Comment: I got that you dont use them. Start using them? Bake one Navmesh while having the objects/islands marked as walkable. This should produce "spots" of the Navmesh on the islands which you can connect with offMeshLink and do your thing with disabling the Agent etc.
There wont be a need to find another navmesh, as there are only these spot on the island, which are still counted as one Navmesh